# Disk format 4kn to 512e not happening

Tags: scsi, block

I have pair of 6Tb SAS drives: Toshiba MG04SCA and Seagate Exos 7E8. They both came as 512e earlier and were reformatted with `sg_format --format --size=4096`. Then they were used in 4kn RAID-1 volume.

Now I want them to work with RAID adapter without 4kn support, so my task here is to change 4kn back to 512e. I am using plain HBA to reformat disks to avoid unexpected behavior. Exos 7E8 changed block easily with `SeaChest` utility, it even did not take any time, but Toshiba MG04SCA reformat is not happening.

`sg_format --format --size=512` shows the entire process as it should, no warnings or errors. It takes a day as usual and after successful finish disk still has 4k logical block reported by any utility like fdisk or smartctl. This is no stale information - replugging disk or reboot does not help.

Disk report firmware 5703 if that is important. Would be grateful for any hints about changing disk back to 512e.

Answer (score 1):

Just for everyone to know Toshiba MG04SCA40EA does not support 512e mode. I was sure I was reformatting it before but it seems I am wrong and it came as 4Kn initially. "EA" should be "EE" for 512e.